# accessing of b2Body and b2Fixture properties in different classes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, box2d-iphone

Is it possible to access b2Fixture and b2Body properties in one class in another class in such a way that joints could be created. If yes, how can it be done. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create property to get access to your b2Body object. Then you can get list of b2Fixtures for this b2Body.

in your .h file

```
@interface MyClass
{
    b2Body* m_body;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) b2Body* body;

@end
```

in your .mm file (you must use .mm extension to be able to use c++ classes and methods)

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize body = m_body;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if( self != nil )
    {
        // create your b2Body here and 
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

After this all MyClass instances will have property body, that can be accessed as

```
myClassInstance.body
```

or

```
[myClassInstance body];
```

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could show me a brief example. Thanks in advance

Comment: how can I get the list of b2Fixtures from this b2Body?

Comment: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/fixtures the first link in google by searching "box2d get fixture list" provides good article.